# Permalinks going to 404

Tags: templates

I have a link from my home page:

```
<h1><a href="{title_permalink='projects/view'}">{title}</a></h1>
```

I have the template setup in my folder -> http://cl.ly/QMlL

I can't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: You don't have `{if no_results}{redirect="404}{/if}` in your view template do you?

Comment: My view template is currently static at the moment.

Comment: Oh its because there is no dynamic content.  That's a rookie mistake.  :)

Comment: Hmm, actually that isn't it.

Here is a gist of my view.html https://gist.github.com/NickToye/6048546

and this is my main page which links to the projects.

https://gist.github.com/NickToye/6048547

Anything I am doing wrong there?

Comment: Please, @NickToye, improve your question. What is the link being generated? The link on your images is different of the others ones. Why?

Comment: Sorry how is it different?  

<a href="http://dev.pixelsandcode.co.uk/projects/view/jar-of-stars">Jar of Stars</a>

Comment: Nick - your Gists must be Private, I can't see them. Also, please post what your example URL looks like after following your `title_permalink` link.

Answer (score 1):

It was an .htaccess issue. Nick didn't know that a .htaccess file is need to [remove](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html) the index.php from the URLs.